# Mobile App Plus Offline App error: "Looks like this object isn't configured for offline access. Your admin can help with that"

Tags: mobile, offline

**Steps to recreate**:

1. Create a Briefcase configuring the following Objects; Asset, Location and Work Order. Perform "Run As User" test to verify records exist
2. Login to Salesforce Mobile, while online, choose "Offline App" from the App Launcher, navigate to "My Offline Records"
3. Wait for Briefcase to sync Objects
4. After syncing completes, click on "Assets" and select an Asset record from the list.

**Expected Result**:
Asset is displayed

**Actual Result**:
*NOTE: Error occurs regardless if iPhone is online or not.* Error: "Looks like this object isn't configured for offline access. Your admin can help with that"
[image]